# TimeHandler ever second with constricted Random Generator

Tags: java, android, andengine

So

I have a method that gets called on every second to add sprites to a scene.

What i want to do is be able to control the percentage rate of which sprite gets added when the method is called.

So i tried using

```
Math.Random() > .3;
```

Basically this would be a 30% chance that the sprite would get added...correct?

So the problem with this was that i only have four sprites. So sometimes when the method was called no sprites would be added to the scene, when each time the method is called a sprite is added.

So tried using

```
    Random rand = new Random();

int itemNumber = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;

if (itemNumber == 1) {
```

The problem with this is this is totally controlled by the Random generator. When i want to be able to control the percentage of which sprite is added more or less.

So what would be my way of doing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, this:

```
if(Math.Random() > .3)
```

will pass 70% of the time, not 30%. If you want 30%, change it to `<`

**EDIT:**

Ok, so you want to ensure a sprite is called, and want to be able to control how often each particular sprite is called? What you need is a variable for each sprite that contains the odds of calling it. For example, this will return an int to represent each sprite:

```
final double[] mOdds = {0.10, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35};   
// note, mOdds totals 1.0

public int pickSprite()
{
    double rand = Math.Random();
    for(int i=0;i<mOdds.length;i++)
    {
        if(rand < mOdds[i])
            return i;
        rand -= mOdds[i];
    }
    return -1;                    // should never reach this
}
```

You could use arbitrary numbers in your `mOdds` that don't add to 1.0, but you'd have to modify it a bit. Basically, you just have to make sure that `rand` will give you a number between 0 and the total of all the `mOdds` if you want a sprite every turn.

**Update 2:**

In your drawing routine, you can call the above function to choose the sprite and draw accordingly:

```
...
switch(pickSprite())
{
case 0:
    // draw sprite 0
    break;
case 1:
    // draw sprite 1
    break;
case 2:
    // draw sprite 2
    break;
case 3:
    // draw sprite 3
    break;
}
...
```

Or, if you have the sprites in an array, it's even easier:

```
...
sprite[pickSprite()].draw(); // substitute however you draw
...
```

It all depends on your program flow, really. You should be able to adapt the concept to whatever routine you're using.

Comment: Right i am aware that but how to insure that a sprite is added each time? or will i just simply need to change the greater than sign to <

Comment: Will a sprite be added each time the method is called though with your method?

Comment: Updated. Sorry, I misunderstood the issue here.

Comment: So which variable would be supplied to the if() statement to chose the sprite?

Comment: A switch() may be easier. Just use the function I posted as the parameter. See newest update.

Comment: So how would i go about changing the percentage using your edit? I would like to control the percentage that each sprite gets called.

Comment: The percentages are stored in `mOdds[]`. In my post, they're 10, 25, 30, and 35%, respectively for sprites 0-3. To be able to change them during runtime you'll want to remove the `final` in the declaration. Then you can change them with `mOdds[2] = 0.3;` for example, to change sprite 2's odds to 30%.

Comment: So. what happens if i change the percentage and it doesnt equal 100% ??? Will this mean a sprite wont be called at some point??

Comment: idk if it will work because when i change  {0.10, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35}; to  {0.15, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35}; or something like this..it wont work correctly. It wont add a sprite each time its called in my update handler.

Comment: Hmm, well if they add up to less than 1.0 you might not get a sprite(-1 return). If they total more, you should get one each call, but it will mess up the proportion(it will eat into #3's odds).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct. You need to generate a random number between 1-4 (including 1 and 4).

This code must give you a random number between 1-4 (including 1 and 4).

```
Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
```